# Keras expected embedding_13_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (20, 7, 12)

Tags: python, keras

I know this question has been asked a bunch of times but I just can't resolve this error using any of the answers at SO. I am trying to build embeddings and my data is shaped: (20, 7, 12) i.e. 20 training samples, that have 7 words each, with one-hot encoded to 12 dimensions.

When I fit my model using the below specs, I get the error:

> Error when checking input: expected embedding_24_input to have 2
> dimensions, but got array with shape (20, 7, 12)

```
embedding_dims = 10
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(12, embedding_dims,input_length=7))
```

I then tried to Flatten before Embedding, but that failed complaining that "input_length" is 7, but received input has shape (None, 84)". I then changed the input_length on the embedding layer to match that but no luck with that either:

> Error when checking target: expected embedding_26 to have 3
> dimensions, but got array with shape (20, 12)

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Embedding(12, embedding_dims,input_length=84))
```

I would really appreciate any help with some explanation, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Embedding` layer don't expect the one hot encoding in input data, you should using function like **numpy.argmax** or **tf.argmax** to convert data to integer matrix of size (batch, input_length) before feed data in `Embedding` layer.

Following example working without any error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

embedding_dims = 10
batch_size = 20
vocabulary_size = 12

# The model will take as input an integer matrix of size (batch, input_length), 
# and the largest integer (i.e. word index) in the input should be no larger than 11 (vocabulary size - 1)
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocabulary_size, embedding_dims, input_length=7))
model.compile('rmsprop', 'mse')

raw_input_array = np.random.randint(2, size=(batch_size, 7, vocabulary_size))
input_array = np.argmax(raw_input_array, axis=-1)
output_array = model.predict(input_array)
print("One hot encodeing data shape: {}\ninput integer matrix shape: {}\noutput shape: {}\n".format(raw_input_array.shape, input_array.shape, output_array.shape))
```

Outputs:

```
One hot encodeing data shape: (20, 7, 12)
input integer matrix shape: (20, 7)
output shape: (20, 7, 10)
```

Comment: Sorry, I need to wrap my brain around this. 
1. Isnt the whole point of the Embedding Layer is to convert the sparse one-hot vectors into dense vectors? 
2. Since the argmax is converting the onehot to index, then doesnt that defy the quantitative law? i.e. if two tokens that are unrelated are nearby (by index), then the model with incorrectly assume they are related?

Comment: I think you are over thinking it, check the first line of documentation of [tf.keras.layers.Embedding](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Embedding), what it does is: Turns positive integers (indexes) into dense vectors of fixed size. i.e Embedding layer is a index to vector lookup table, theoretically we could retrieve vector using one-hot vector, but tensorflow implement use index because of efficiency, all the layer after Embedding layer will not directly see the index but only see whatever vector retrieved by index from lookup table, so no need worry about that law